# C++ error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type char&

Tags: c++, g++

Начал изучать c++ и в процессе изучения массивов строк столкнулся с несколькими ошибками, которые самостоятельно понять не получается.
Вот полный код:

```
#include <iostream>  // std::cout
#include <cstdio>    // gets
#include <cstring>   // strcmp
using namespace std;

/* func declarations */
int main();
void displayMenu();
void displayWorkers(char&, int); // &workers - означает, что необходимо рассматривать аргумент как указатель (внутри функции * не используется)

/* variables declarations */
char workers[][2][30] = {
    "Alex", "22-33-44", "24300",
    "Ivan", "55-33-66", "30000",
    "Pavel", "22-33-44", "24300",
    "Антон", "", "25000",
    "Жора", "44-33-11", "25000"
};
char projects[][2] = {};

/* functions */

int main() {
    char listen[120];
    // show menu
    do {
        displayMenu();
        fflush (stdout);
        scanf("%119s", listen);
        if (strcmp(listen, "1") == 0) {
            displayWorkers(&workers, 5);
        } else if (strcmp(listen, "2") == 0) {
            cout << " -- Projects --\n";
        }
    } while (strcmp(listen, "quit") != 0);
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Display menu
 */
void displayMenu() {
    cout << " == Menu ==\n";
    cout << " 1 - Показать всех работников\n";
    cout << " 2 - Показать все проекты\n";
    cout << " quit - Выход\n";
}

/**
 * displayWorkers
 * @param workers
 * @param count
 */
void displayWorkers(char &workers, int count) {
    int i;
    cout << "Workers\n Name\t\t|Phone\t\t|Salary\n";
    for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << workers[i][0] << "\t\t|" << workers[i][1] << "\t\t|" << workers[i][2] << "\n";
    }
}
```

Вот ошибки которые я получаю при компиляции:

```
$ g++ study1.cpp -o study
study1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
study1.cpp:36:39: error: invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘char&’ from an rvalue of type ‘char (*)[8][2][30]’
             displayWorkers(&workers, 5);
                                       ^
study1.cpp:14:6: error: in passing argument 1 of ‘void     displayWorkers(char&, int)’
 void displayWorkers(char&, int); // &workers - означает, что     необходимо рассматривать аргумент как указатель (внутри функции * не     используется)
      ^
study1.cpp: In function ‘void displayWorkers(char&, int)’:
study1.cpp:64:26: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
         cout << workers[i][0] << "\t\t|" << workers[i][1] << "\t\t|"     << workers[i][2] << "\n";
                          ^
study1.cpp:64:54: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
         cout << workers[i][0] << "\t\t|" << workers[i][1] << "\t\t|"     << workers[i][2] << "\n";
                                                      ^
study1.cpp:64:82: error: invalid types ‘char[int]’ for array subscript
         cout << workers[i][0] << "\t\t|" << workers[i][1] << "\t\t|"     << workers[i][2] << "\n";
```

Очень надеюсь на указание конкретно моих ошибок, а не закидывание ссылками, так как уже искал долго и упорно, но безрезультатно.

Comment: Всем большое спасибо! Буду разбираться.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы путаете *ссылки* и *указатели*. Это не одно и то же (на уровне C++).

### Ссылка:

- Нельзя изменить ссылку (нельзя сослаться на другой объект)
- Ссылку не надо разыменовывать при получении доступа к объекту на который она ссылается

### Указатель:

- Можно изменить указатель (*указать* на другой объект)
- При получении доступа к объекту, на который он указывает, необходимо разыменовывать указатель

Таким образом, указатели потенциально менее безопасны.

В Вашем случае, Вы определяете функцию, которая принимает первым аргументом *ссылку на char*. Это значит, что по этой ссылке Вы можете изменить переданный извне символ, не более.

Я бы посоветовал Вам переписать программу следующим образом:

1. Добавить в нее класс, который будет представлять работника.
2. Убрать глобальные переменные.
3. Заменить теплые ламповые (но очень неудобные) массивы символов на `std::string`.
4. Воспользоваться оберткой `std::vector`, для представления динамических массивов.

Answer (score 0):

Вот это

```
char workers[][2][30] = {
    "Alex", "22-33-44", "24300",
    "Ivan", "55-33-66", "30000",
    "Pavel", "22-33-44", "24300",
    "Антон", "", "25000",
    "Жора", "44-33-11", "25000"
};
```

Определяет 3-х мерный массив типа `char`, который Вы пытаетесь наполнять в стиле одномерного массива типа `const char*`. Судя по данным, которые Вы используете Вам нужна структура и одномерный массив. Если это C++, то можно сделать это, например, так:
Сама структура:

```
struct Employee
{
    std::string m_Name;
    std::string m_Number;
    std::string m_AnotherNumber;

    Employee(const std::string& name, const std::string& number, 
        const std::string& anotherNumber) : 
        m_Name(name),
        m_Number(number),
        m_AnotherNumber(anotherNumber)
    {

    }
};
```

использование:

```
Employee workers[] = {
    Employee("Alex", "22-33-44", "24300"),
    Employee("Ivan", "55-33-66", "30000"),
    Employee("Pavel", "22-33-44", "24300"),
    Employee("Антон", "", "25000"),
    Employee("Жора", "44-33-11", "25000")
};

std::cout << workers[2].m_Name << "\n";
```

displayWorkers, соответственно, будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
void displayWorkers(Employee workers[], int count) 
{
    std::cout << "Workers\n Name\t\t|Phone\t\t|Salary\n";
    for(int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        std::cout << workers[i].m_Name << "\t\t|" << workers[i].m_Number << "\t\t|" 
            << workers[i].m_AnotherNumber << "\n";
    }
}
```

---

Ну и раз уж C++, то дополним пример до нормального C++ решения:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee(const std::string& name, const std::string& number, 
        const std::string& anotherNumber) : 
        m_Name(name),
        m_Number(number),
        m_AnotherNumber(anotherNumber)
    {

    }
    std::string name() const
    {
        return m_Name;
    }

    std::string number() const
    {
        return m_Number;
    }

    std::string anotherNumber() const
    {
        return m_AnotherNumber;
    }
private:
    std::string m_Name;
    std::string m_Number;
    std::string m_AnotherNumber;
};

void displayWorkers(const std::vector<Employee>& workers) 
{
    size_t fieldSize = 15;
    std::cout << std::setw(20) << "Workers\n";
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(fieldSize) << "Name" <<
        std::setw(fieldSize) << "Phone" << std::setw(fieldSize) << "Salary";
    std::cout << "\n\n";
    for(auto worker: workers) {
        std::cout << std::setw(fieldSize) << worker.name() << std::setw(fieldSize) 
            << worker.number() << std::setw(fieldSize)
            << worker.anotherNumber() << "\n";
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<Employee>  workers = {
        {"Alex", "22-33-44", "24300"},
        {"Ivan", "55-33-66", "30000"},
        {"Pavel", "22-33-44", "24300"},
        {"Антон", "", "25000"},
        {"Жора", "44-33-11", "25000"}
    };

    displayWorkers(workers);

    return 0;
}
```

Будет оно Вам в качестве домашнего задания.

Answer (score 0):

Для начала, если вы уж пишете на C++, пользуйтесь идиоматическими контейнерами. Никаких `char[][][][]`, из которых одни скобки указывают на то, что это строка, а другие — на то, что это массив.

Затем, тройка элементов `"Alex", "22-33-44", "24300"` — это не просто три какие-то строки, они представляют собой вещи с различной семантикой, и очевидным образом объединяются в одну структуру.

Затем, вы в вашем коде определяете там и тут какие-то магические константы: 30, 120 и т. п. Надеюсь, вы понимаете, чем это грозит. Если нет, подумайте сами.

Теперь по конкретной ошибке. Согласно вашему коду, процедура `displayWorkers` требует первым аргументом `char&` — то есть, ссылку (не указатель) на `char` (то есть, один символ). Вы же как передаёте, так и используете внутри структуру `workers`.

Ваш код должен выглядеть как-то так:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

/* types */
struct worker {
    string name;
    string phone;
    unsigned salary;
};

/* func declarations */
void displayMenu();
void displayWorkers(const vector<worker>&);

/* global variables */
vector<worker> workers = {
    { "Alex", "22-33-44", 24300 },
    { "Ivan", "55-33-66", 30000 },
    { "Pavel", "22-33-44", 24300 },
    { "Антон", "", 25000 },
    { "Жора", "44-33-11", 25000 }
};

/* functions */

int main() {
    string listen;
    // show menu
    do {
        displayMenu();
        getline(cin, listen);
        if (listen == "1") 
            displayWorkers(workers);
        } else if (listen == "2") {
            cout << " -- Projects --\n";
        }
    } while (listen != "quit");
    return 0;
}

/**
 * Display menu
 */
void displayMenu() {
    cout << " == Menu ==\n";
    cout << " 1 - Показать всех работников\n";
    cout << " 2 - Показать все проекты\n";
    cout << " quit - Выход\n";
}

/**
 * displayWorkers
 * @param workers
 */
void displayWorkers(const vector<worker>&workers) {
    cout << "Workers\n Name\t\t|Phone\t\t|Salary\n";
    for (auto& w : workers) {
        cout << w.name << "\t\t|" << w.phone << "\t\t|" << w.salary << "\n";
    }
}
```

Проверка: http://ideone.com/YOdMsy